# citestyle=authortitle-icomp, but including year?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am nearly totally happy with

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle-icomp,bibstyle=authortitle,dashed=no,datezeros=no]{biblatex}
```

because it shows the author and the (short) title in citations, but I would like to have the year in the citation too.

Here is the mwe:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,twoside,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle-icomp,bibstyle=authortitle,dashed=no,datezeros=no]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mwe.bib}
\begin{document}
Heyho, \Footcite{BVerfGOD} yeah.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Where the mwe.bib is

```
@Book{BVerfGOD,
  entrysubtype  = {urteil},
  author    = {Bundesverfassungsgericht},
  sortname  = {Bundesverfassungsgericht},
  title     = {Bundesverfassungsgerichtsurteil zur Online-Durchsuchung},
  subtitle  = {BVerfG, 1 BvR 370/07},
  publisher = {},
  year      = {27.2.2008},
  address   = {},
  edition   = {},
  url       = {http://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/entscheidungen/rs20080227_1bvr037007.html}
}
```

This results in a citation of

```
Bundesverfassungsgericht, Bundesverfassungsgerichtsurteil zur Online-Durchsuchung.
```

But I would like to get

```
Bundesverfassungsgericht, Bundesverfassungsgerichtsurteil zur Online-Durchsuchung, 27.2.2008.
```

Now my question is: did I miss a citestyle preset or do I have to create a macro myself for this? Authoryear (obviously) does not print the title. (The bibstyle/bibliography is fine.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You want the year "at the end" ? Meaning, in the bibliography, or when you cite (or both) ?

Comment: Ok, MWE provided, thx.

Comment: Would the date only appear in the initial citation?

Comment: Nope, always (except ibidem). I think, the date is not much space and always showing it prevents the need for searching the initial mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Titles in citations are generated by the `cite:title` bibliography macro. You can add dates/years by redefining this in your preamble with:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printdate}}
```

or

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate}
```

Note that you should use `date = {2008-02-27}` instead of `year = {27.2.2008}`. Further details on date formatting can be found in the biblatex manual section "Date Specifications".